# How to rate limit vertx API calls?

Tags: http, vert.x, vertx-verticle, vertx-httpclient

I have a Vertx API where users can perform http POST, but i want to rate limit the same person/ ip address from spamming API calls, like a 30 second rate limit before they can do it again.

Where and how can i implement this rate limit in my vertx API code?

This is my starter:

```
public class Starter extends AbstractVerticle {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Starter.class.getSimpleName());
    private static final String HTTP_PORT = "http.port";
    private static final Integer HTTP_FALLBACK_PORT = 8000;

    public Starter() {
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Promise<Void> startPromise) throws ParseException {
        vertx
            .createHttpServer()
            .requestHandler(buildRoutes(enableCors()))
            .listen(config().getInteger(HTTP_PORT, HTTP_FALLBACK_PORT),
                asyncResult -> listener(asyncResult, startPromise));


    }

    private Router buildRoutes(final Router router) throws ParseException {
        new MovieApi(router);
        router.errorHandler(500, this::handle500Error);
        return router;
    }

    private void handle500Error(RoutingContext routingContext) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Internal Server Error", routingContext.failure());
    }

    private Router enableCors() {
        var router = Router.router(vertx);
        router.route().handler(CorsHandler.create(".*.")
                                   .allowedHeader("x-requested-with")
                                   .allowedHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin")
                                   .allowedHeader("origin")
                                   .allowedHeader("Content-Type")
                                   .allowedHeader("accept")
                                   .allowedMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                                   .allowedMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                                   .allowedMethod(HttpMethod.DELETE)
                                   .allowedMethod(HttpMethod.PUT));
        router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());
        return router;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(Promise<Void> endFuture) {
        vertx.close(completionHandler -> endFuture.complete());
    }

    private void listener(final AsyncResult<HttpServer> res, Promise<Void> startPromise) {
        if (res.succeeded()) {
            startPromise.complete();
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO,
                () -> String.format("Server is listening on port: %s", res.result().actualPort()));
        } else {
            startPromise.fail("Failed to start http server");
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO,
                () -> String.format("Failed to bind on port: %s", config()
                                                                      .getInteger(HTTP_PORT, HTTP_FALLBACK_PORT)));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        var vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        vertx.deployVerticle(Starter.class.getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Vert.x handlers are just an implementation of Chain of Responsibility pattern. And you can easily implement one yourself:

```java
...
router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());
router.route().handler(new MyRateLimiter());
...
```

The `MyRateLimiter` class will have to implement a single method:

```java
void handle(RoutingContext rc)
```

How you implement the logic of rate limiting is really up to you. You can store the IPs in Redis with a TTL, or use a shared map, or some other solution that works for you.

If everything is fine, you then invoke `rc.next()`

If you want to ratelimit, you can use `rc.fail(503)`, for example.

The recommended approach nowadays for rate limiting in Vert.x is to integrate with Resilience4J:
https://how-to.vertx.io/resilience4j-howto/

Comment: So the Vertx ecosystem is so small that not only rate-limiting hasn't been done, but there are also no plans to have a common/shared implementation in the future? Everyone will keep reinventing the wheel, as many times as it takes?

Comment: @VictorPudeyev, first, I'd like to point out that this answer is 2.5 years old. And second, here's the recommended approach now:
https://how-to.vertx.io/resilience4j-howto/

Comment: Cool! I'll try that. Also for posterity, there seems to be an available implementation: https://github.com/badrazizi/vertx-rate-limiter